# XLS-Furmular is broken. when updating values

Tags: excel, openxml, formula

I use OpenXML to modify an xlsx - file.

This file contains formulars like "=SUM(A1;Z1)"

I modify the cell values that are used in the formular, like setting C1 to "45"

The format of these cells are Numbers.

When I only Insert "0" into these cells, the Excel file is loaded. I can change the values afterwards in Excel, with the calculation done correctly.

But when I add different values like "34" I get an error when Opening the file and the formular is gone.

Code for edding the values:

```
Cell cell = GetCell(sheet.Worksheet, column, row);

cell.CellValue = new CellValue(value);
cell.DataType = new EnumValue<CellValues>(valueType)
```

(valueType=Number)

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly know the cause of your problem, but I do know that OpenXML makes life very difficult. If you haven't heard of [ClosedXML](http://closedxml.codeplex.com) you should definitely take a look at it. It is a free library that makes working with XSLX file way easier. ClosedXML is also available as a NuGet package to make it easy to get started.